# Is leftsemi faster with smaller table on the left side?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

[Join operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/joinoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer) documentation says:

> Tip
>
> For best performance, if one table is always smaller than the
> other, use it as the left (piped) side of the join.

The purpose of [leftsemi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/joinoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer#left-semi-join-flavor) in most cases is to filter a bigger set on the left by a smaller set on the right. Is the quote above still applicable to `leftsemi` flavor of join operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least at this point, Tables' order does matter.

Here is a quick test results, executed on my dev cluster:

**Setup**

```
.set-or-replace L100M <| range i from 1 to 100000000 step 1

.set-or-replace S1M <| range i from 1 to 1000000 step 1 | project i = tolong(rand(100000000))
```

---

**rightsemi** (small table first)

```
S1M | join kind=rightsemi L100M on i | consume
```

Query completes in around 3 seconds

---

**leftsemi** (large table first)

```
L100M | join kind=leftsemi S1M on i | consume
```

Query runs about 20 seconds and then fails with the following exception:

> Query execution lacks memory resources to complete (80DA0007): Partial
> query failure: Low memory condition (E_LOW_MEMORY_CONDITION).
> (message: 'bad allocation', details: '').